# cxf webservice over jms, how to get wsdl

Tags: web-services, jms, cxf

I have a webservice configured like this.

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="helloWorld"
    xmlns:hello="http://service.test.com/"
    serviceName="hello:MyServiceImplService"
    endpointName="hello:MyServiceImplPort" address="jms://"
    implementor="com.test.service.MyServiceImpl" >
        <jaxws:features>          
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />      
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfigFeature">
                <property name="jmsConfig" ref="jmsConfig"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:features>
  </jaxws:endpoint>`
```

I want to have the cxf generate the wsdl for me. when the service is http, I can access the wsdl from a url like this `http://localhost:8080/server/hello?wsdl`, after I change the transport to jms, how do I access the wsdl? what's the jms message I need to send to get the wsdl. or I have to write the wsdl first and expose it through a regular http request. I am asking this because the client need to know the wsdl to get all the type and binding information to generate class. client should already know how to connect the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use commandline java2ws tool (see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html) passing it your implementation class. There is also a sample invocation from Ant script. It will generate WSDL which your client can use to generate client code.